# Updating pyqt widget content from another widget

Tags: python, forms, widget, pyqt, updates

Moving on from my last question, I'm stuck once again. I'm trying to update content of parent widget from child widget. The code seems to work first time but after closing and re-opening the form widget it does not update the parent widget.

Following is the code.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from functools import partial
import sys


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

       self.main_widget()

    def main_widget(self):
        self.form = Form()
        self.simple = Simple()
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()


        self.last_input_label = QtGui.QLabel("")
        grid.addWidget(self.last_input_label, 1, 0, 3, 1)

        show_form_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Form")
        show_form_button.clicked.connect(partial(self.form.show_form, self.last_input_label))
        grid.addWidget(show_form_button, 0, 0)

        show_simple_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Simple")
        show_simple_button.clicked.connect(self.simple.show_simple)
        grid.addWidget(show_simple_button, 0, 1)

        another_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Print Hello")
        another_button.clicked.connect(partial(print, "Hello"))
        grid.addWidget(another_button, 0, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Widget")
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        QtGui.QApplication.closeAllWindows()


class Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print("form initialized")
        super(Form, self).__init__()

    def show_form(self, last_input_label):
        print("form called")
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.last_input_label = last_input_label

        label = QtGui.QLabel("Name")
        grid.addWidget(label, 0, 0)


        self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        grid.addWidget(self.line_edit, 0, 1)

        self.submit_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Submit")
        self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.print_form_data)
        grid.addWidget(self.submit_button, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(250, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Form Widget")
        self.show()

    def get_form_data(self):
        form_data = {
            "name": self.line_edit.text()
        }
        return form_data

    def print_form_data(self):
        self.x = self.get_form_data()
        for item in self.x:
            print(item + ": " + self.x[item])
            self.last_input_label.setText(self.x[item])

        return


class Simple(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        print("simple initialized")
        super(Simple, self).__init__()

    def show_simple(self):
        print("simple called")
        self.setGeometry(300, 250, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Widget")
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_widget = MainWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the initialization code each time you show the widget. Move all that into the `__init__` method where it belongs and it all works.

Move everything beside this into the init method. I can't say exactly why running the init code more would break the connection. But somehow it does. Maybe someone else can fill in that detail.

```
def show_form(self, last_input_label):
    print("form called")
    self.last_input_label = last_input_label
    self.show()
```

Comment: Thanx for the help @M4rtini it worked. Also figured out that only moving self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit() into the __init__ method will do the job. But for the layout's sake I moved all the initializing statements to the __init__ method and now it all works fine.